# How to choose the best hashing algorithm when taking into account collisions' rate and speed of hash generation?

Tags: string, md5, checksum, difference, sha

If I have a CSS file that is generated dynamically, which function should I use to generate a short identifying string for the whole file content?

md5 or crc32 ? other?

Comment: md5 will do just fine.

Comment: I don't get the title-question though

Comment: @Max If the content of the file (data) has changed, then the checksum will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is simply this: md5 should be enough.

The longer answer is:

Depends... how many files are we talking about. The theoretical maximum of unique hashes generated with md5 is 2^64, but you have to take the birthday problem into account.
But with a couple of million file hashes, the chance of a hash collision increases by more than a simple 1/2^64th (2<sup>-128</sup>).

If you are dealing with a *"vast"* number of files, I'd choose a safer hasing algorithm. I'd say using sha1 makes sense. Especially given the fact that the added overhead/cost is negligible on modern day computers.
If we're talking about a dozen or so files, then md5 is more than enough. Using sha1, though, isn't being silly. It's a reasonably fast, and quite reliable hash. Though it is, in theory, no longer deemed *secure*, collisions haven't been observed out in the wild, AFAIK.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) backs this up, saying:

> A 2011 attack by Marc Stevens can produce hash collisions with a complexity of 2<sup>61</sup> operations. No actual collisions have yet been produced.

Either way, 2<sup>61</sup> should be more than enough.

Oh, and in case you are wondering: [The birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) is explained here

***Applied to your use-case***
Since you're hashing files, using a php function like [`md5_file`](http://www.php.net/md5_file) does look tempting. But, possibly because md5 has been shown to be unsafe, PHP comes with [a `sha1_file`](http://www.php.net/sha1_file) function.
Using `crc32` might, at first, seem like a valid option, because it was developed with the intent to generate hashes to check file integrity. But it really is quite old, and because the hash itself is only 32bit, it stands to reason that the risk of collision is greater than it is with md5, or sha1.

Compare:

```
|-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Comp. | CRC32 |  MD5  |  SHA1  |
+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Bits  |  32   |  128  |  160   |
+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| c.rest|  2^16 |  2^18 |  2^61  | (sha1 in theory)
+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| crypt |  No   |  No   |  No    |
+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| cost  |   1   |   2   |  3.1   | (crc32 used as base)
+-------+-------+-------+--------+
 * c.rest: collision resistance
 * crypt: Cryptographically secure
```

*Note on cost value:*
I've run some PHP scripts comparing the time it takes to compute the hashes. A million hashes of random strings of approx. 15 chars long took just over 0.25 microseconds. md5 hashes were computed in just over half a second (results ranged from 0.43 to 0.56, converging on 0.55). The sha1 hashes were generated in 0.78 microseconds (results ranged from 0.76 to 0.8001). The time taken refers to the time it took to generate *all* 1,000,000 hashes.

*more:*

Formula fro CRC32 collision [here](http://www.quora.com/Hashing/What-is-the-probability-of-having-CRC32-collision-on-simple-strings)
[md5 collision resistance quoted on the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

Here's a random-string generator that allows you to test how *"common"* hash collisions are:

```
<?php
class RSGen
{
    private $pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    private $max = 61;
    private $hashed = array();

    public function randomUniqueString($len = 15)
    {
        $str = '';
        for ($i=0;$i<$len;++$i)
        {
            $str .= substr($this->pool, mt_rand(0, $this->max),1);
        }
        $hash = crc32($str);
        if (isset($this->hashed[$hash]))
        {
            for ($i=0,$j=count($this->hashed[$hash]);$i<$j;++$i)
            {
                if ($this->hashed[$hash][$i] === $str)
                {
                    return $this->randomUniqueString($len);
                }
            }
            echo 'Collision: ', $hash, PHP_EOL, $str, PHP_EOL, implode(', ', $this->hashed[$hash]), PHP_EOL;
            return false;
        }
        else
            $this->hashed[$hash] = array();
        $this->hashed[$hash][] = $str;
        return $str;
    }
}
$gen = new RSGen();
for($i=0;$i<1000000;++$i)
{
    $str = $gen->randomUniqueString();
    if ($str === false)
    {
        echo PHP_EOL,'Collision after ', $i, ' tries', PHP_EOL;
        break;
    }
}
```

Open this in vim, and replace all hashing function calls with the hash of your choice. Using `crc32`, collisions are almost always found.
To test `md5`

```
:%s/crc32/md5/g
```

Same for `sha1`:

```
:%s/crc32/sha1/g
```

Comment: thanks I think I`ll go with md5() on the file modification time :)

Comment: @Alex: The modification time is not the most reliable way to determine when a file was last altered, though: to set the time to _"now"_, without changing the file contents: `touch someFile`. Not too bad, but I could well change the file, and then set the modification time to its previous value, seemingly leave the file unchanged: `vim someFile` [edit & save] `touch -t 201401010000.00 someFile` -> file was seemingly last changed 01-01-2014 at exactly midnight. Replace the digits with the time prior to my editing the file and your code wouldn't spot the difference